# Trying to get MySql order by count, but only getting 1 of each

Tags: mysql

I'm sure this is probably something simple that I'm missing, but I'm trying to do a MySQL query that counts the occurrence of each item in a row, and the returns a result that has the entire row, ordered by count.

For example, I have a row with these entries:

```
 Agriculture
 Energy
 Energy
 Environment
 Agriculture
 Mining
 Energy
```

I want my query to return to me:

```
 Energy
 Energy
 Energy
 Agriculture 
 Agriculture
 Environment
 Mining
```

I'm trying this:

```
SELECT  `companyname`, `id`, `location`,`industry`, COUNT(`industry`) AS `industry_occurrence`  
FROM atl3_atl_testimonials 
WHERE state ='1'  
ORDER BY industry_occurrence
```

But it is only returning the first "Energy" result, rather than all the results, ordered by occurrence. What should I change?

Comment: is it mandatory to have the `industry_occurence` column? i suspect the `count` implicitly executes `group by`.

Comment: How are you using count without group by? U did not hit an error?

Comment: @Valli MySQL does not produce an error on this. You can use every aggregation without proper grouping - it's just wrong (most the time), but no error. Especially the ungrouped columns might return anything but the expected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are looking for one such here.

```
SELECT  `companyname`, `id`, `location`,
         a.industry, cnt AS `industry_occurrence`  
  FROM atl3_atl_testimonials a,
       (SELECT COUNT(`industry`) cnt,  `industry`
          FROM atl3_atl_testimonials
      Group by industry) f
  WHERE state ='1' 
    AND f.industry = a.industry  
ORDER BY cnt desc
```